# Create simple logo in tikz

Tags: backgrounds, logos

How can I make a 400 x 400 pixel logo with tikz, having a background color and a text with a specific font on top?

I guess I should use

```
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{tikzpicture}[background/.style={fill=black}, color=white]
```

Comment: You don't need `backgrounds`, just draw a square first, everything else will be placed on top.

Comment: 400x400 what?  pixels? pt? cm?

Comment: 400x400 pixels. Sorry

Comment: Why would you use TikZ for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to be limited in the choice of fonts, use `fontspec` and compile with `xelatex` or `lualatex`. You asked elsewhere about converting PDF to PNG, but I show one way of doing it here as well, using the `standalone` class.

Requirements:

- ImageMagick must be installed.
- You have to compile with `shell-escape` enabled.

**Note on DPI:**
I made a 4cm by 4cm square. With a resolution of 254ppi you will get 100 pixels per centimeter, so 4cm gives 400 pixels.

As far as the design goes, you just asked for a colored square with some text on top, so that is what you got.

[image]

```
% arara: xelatex: { shell: yes }
\documentclass[convert={png,density=254}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\logofont{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill [use as bounding box,blue!20] (0,0) rectangle (4cm,4cm);
\node [font=\logofont\bfseries\scshape\Large,align=center] at (2cm,2cm) {Gentleman\\Bastards};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```